# Google ExportSheetData: Export XML with more than one atribute column

Tags: xml, google-sheets, attributes, spreadsheet, google-docs

I'm creating a new spreadsheet on Google with some columns for looping by row.

```
    <filme>
        <dia>1</dia>
        <geral href="file:///F:/Dropbox/Telecine/Filmes%20Capas/Um Tio Quase Perfeito 2.jpg"/>
        <now href="file:///F:/Dropbox/Telecine/Filmes%20Capas/Sócias em Guerra.jpg"/>
        <sky href="file:///F:/Dropbox/Telecine/Filmes%20Capas/Sócias em Guerra.jpg"/>
    </filme>
    <filme>
        <dia>2</dia>
        <geral href="file:///F:/Dropbox/Telecine/Filmes%20Capas/Cantando Na Chuva.jpg"/>
        <now href="file:///F:/Dropbox/Telecine/Filmes%20Capas/Os Irmãos Sisters.jpg"/>
        <sky href="file:///F:/Dropbox/Telecine/Filmes%20Capas/Os Irmãos Sisters.jpg"/>
    </filme>
```

I need to indicate some attributes in some columns but the ExportSheetData only accepts placing an attribute in the first column.
Does anyone know how to configure this in ExportSheetData or if there is any other component that exports XML in this way?

Thanks.

Comment: At first, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand about your question, I have questions for your question. 1. What is your value in your question? 2. What is Google ExportSheetData? 3. Can you provide the sample input and output situation you expect? 4. In your tags, `google-docs` is included. In this case, your question is related to Google Document?

Comment: No problem, my English is also terrible.
Answering...
1) In personal terms, I don't have a lot of knowledge in programming, but a solution would be very welcome.
2) ExportSheetData is a component of Google's spreadsheets for exporting data in XML and Json format.
3) The problem is simple. The component uses a tag to specify which column would be identified as an attribute in the XML row. But I can configure only one column per spreadsheet. I need to identify two or more columns with attributes.
4) Yes, my question is related to Google documents, more specifically to spreadsheets.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About my question 1, in this case, I asked about the value showing in your question like `<filme>,,,</filme>,,,`. And, I thought that when you provide the sample input and output situation (values) you expect, it will help users think of the solution. And, Google Document is different from Google Spreadsheet. I could understand that your question is related to Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: Yes, is the Google spreadsheet.
What I need is like this:
`<filme><geral href="link_image"/><now href="link_image"/><sky href="link_image"/></filme>`
And what I can export through ExportSheetData is this:
`<filme><geral> href="link_image"</geral><now>href="link_image"</now><sky>href="link_image"</sky></filme>`
I need the links to be as attributes in each row of different columns.
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't still understand about your sample input and output situations you expect. I apologize for my poor English skill again. But, I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for all.